# $H^s(\mathbb{R^n})$ is stable by product if $s \gt \frac{n}{2}$

Tags: normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

We define the **Sobolev Space** of order $s \in \mathbb{R}$ by:

$H^s(\mathbb{R^n})=${$f \in S'(\mathbb{R^n})$ s.t  $(1+|\xi|^2)$$^\frac{s}{2}\hat{f} \in L^2(\mathbb{R^n)}$}

**My question is**, why if $s \gt \frac{n}{2}$, and $f$, $g \in H^s(\mathbb{R^n})$, then $f.g  \in H^s(\mathbb{R^n})$

and

$||fg||_{H^s(\mathbb{R^n})} \le cst.||f||_{H^s(\mathbb{R^n})}.||g||_{H^s(\mathbb{R^n})}$?

I need some help please

Comment: Did you forget the Fourier transform of $f$ in the definition?

Comment: @user10354138 yes, sorry Ill fix it

Comment: Hint: The norm of $H^s$ is equivalent to $\lVert (1+\lvert\xi\rvert^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}\rVert_{L^2}$.  Note that there exists $C(s)$ such that $(1+x+y)^s\leq C(s)[(1+x)^s+(1+y)^s]$ for all $x,y\geq 0$ so you can estimate the convolution.